# Ruined Ubuntu Bubble notifications

Tags: notification, notify-osd

I don't know now, but somehow today I ruined my Bubble notifications in Ubuntu 12.04

Now my Bubble notifications look like the ones in the pictures: huge, out of place and ugly.

I have tried notify-osd to correct this problem, but it doesn't do anything.

Can anyone tell me how I can reverse to what they look like in default Ubuntu?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with gnome-session-fallback.

Pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to reboot after using notify-osd.

Comment: If you wanted to add a screenshot and couldnt because you have not (yet) enough reputation you may do so by providing a link to an upload. We will then be able to include the shot for you.

Comment: I already tried installing, reinstalling, rebooting and mess around with nofitfy-osd but nothing changes.

Comment: Run following commands:`sudo apt-get remove notification-daemon`. `sudo apt-get install notify-osd`. or if it is already installed run: `sudo dpkg --reconfigure notify-osd`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you installed Gnome, and it overrode notify-osd with notification-daemon. Remove the notification-daemon with:

```
sudo apt-get remove notification-deamon
```

Then reinstall notify-osd:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd
```

Restart:

```
sudo reboot
```